# I want to make a discord bot paste a random image from unsplash.com

Tags: discord.py

i looked around and i managed to get this code:

```
@bot.command()
async def image(ctx):
      embed=discord.Embed(title="Image", color=0x4797ff)
      embed.set_image(url='https://source.unsplash.com/random')       
      embed.set_footer(text="")
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

the command works
but it always gives me the same image
, im not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

i fixed it and decided to post here incase someone gets the same problem

```
import aiohttp
@bot.command()
async def image(ctx):  
      async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as s:
        async with s.get('https://source.unsplash.com/random') as r:
          await ctx.send(r.url)
```

Comment: Your solution is better than mine as its more async, while mine is blocking

Answer (score 1):

This is because of Discord's caching. Discord assumes that a single link will always lead to the same content, and in the case of Unsplash's "random" links that is not the case. Nevertheless, once Discord's servers have downloaded this image once, they don't redownload it for a while, and when the same link appears a second time they serve the image from their own servers.

Both @FierySpectre and @Issa Al-Salmi used the same idea in their answer: first request this image yourself, follow the redirect, and then display the image that the redirect points to. This works, but you might be concerned about the fact that you're downloading the image needlessly.

You can avoid this by setting a [query parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) with a random value -- servers ignore those parameters they didn't expect, and Discord will cache each of these separately. You can use a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) to generate a unique value.

```py
import uuid

...

@bot.command()
async def image(ctx):
      embed=discord.Embed(title="Image", color=0x4797ff)
      embed.set_image(url='https://source.unsplash.com/random?id=' + str(uuid.uuid4()))
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

The person asking the question answered it too, in a better way at that. You should probably use his solution, not mine.

I'm gonna be honest in saying that I have no idea why exactly that happens. I suspect it's discord loading it once, then detecting the same link is already cached and not getting a new image. I was able to fix the issue by using requests to get a different page every time, in that way discord doesn't have to get the image every time(as you get a direct link to the image yourself). Also all the users see the same image now.

code:

```
@bot.command()
async def image(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Image", color=0x4797ff)
    img = requests.get('https://source.unsplash.com/random')
    embed.set_image(url=img.url)
    embed.set_footer(text="")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

of course you have to include `import request` at the top of your program too